# Is this the right choice for realtime notifications? php + Ratchet (websockets)

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I'm new to websocket and realtime applications and I would need some clarifications.

I developed an application for a customer that involve some users and product data.
It is a `PHP` web application running on the internal apache server.
The client side of the app is based mainly on JQuery, and for some parts usable from tablet devices we used `JQuery mobile` / `html5`.

Now the customer is asking to add some messaging/notification feature in this way:
a user will be able to post a message about a product and the web console of the other users must be "showed" a realtime notification. We are thinking to add something for example in the header of the page to notify that new messages are present.

I made some research and as all the app is already built in PHP I was thinking to go for [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs). Is this a good idea?

If I understood this well, I will need to install on the server also the ratchet server components and use for client side integration something like [AutobahnJS](http://autobahn.ws/js) library; is it right?

Has anyone already built something like this?
Is there any problem communicating between Apache and Ratchet server?

Answer (score 2):

That okie,

I tried use Ratchet/AutobahnJs Websocket, that's awesome. But I have (special?) problem :o in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334989/ratchet-websocket-cant-send-data-to-client).

In your case, I think you can use AJAX, it's simpler than Websocket. You can "zip" multi-notifications in to 1 response and request server every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's a good way to go about it, ajax leaves you with a lot of overheads. it's pretty simple to get going with ratchet and it will give you the ability to send notifications in real time, as well as the notifications it will allow you to edit the page as well, i.e change counters/ icons / message count etc, basically same as ajax only in realtime and no need to poll for new data.

It also means you'll be learning some new stuff which is always a bonus, for this alone i would do it.